# there a way to drop 'sysmessages' table from one database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Unfortunately, I created a table called 'sysmessages' in SQL Server 2008. When I restored the DB to SQL Server 2012, I realized that I have two Tables called 'sysmessages'.

I don't want to change my table name because it has been used in the code.

Can I remove only from specific database system table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. it is not a table, but a view
2. of course you cannot remove it, but you don't need to. It is in a different schema. You will not address it like `select * from sys.sysmessages`, you will address it like `select * from dbo.sysmessages`
3. "i don't want to change my table name because it is used in the code" - you can/should change the code as well :)

edit - no. 2. is not applicable in SQL 2012, however it is tested and working in SQL 2008R2

Comment: I haven't tested but likely `select * from dbo.sysmessages` will still end up selecting from the system view for backwards compatibility reasons as it was in the dbo schema in 2000.

Comment: @MartinSmith true, unlike SQL 2008R2 in SQL 2012 it really ends up selecting from the sys.sysmessages

Answer (score 1):

You cant drop system tables,your best bet is to change your code